# Is it possible to buffer output to Log4j Mail Appender?

Tags: java, email, logging, log4j

In many service applications where log4j is used in combination with a mail appender as such ..

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, MAIL
log4j.appender.MAIL=org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender
log4j.appender.MAIL.BufferSize=1
log4j.appender.MAIL.SMTPHost=smtp.example.com
log4j.appender.MAIL.From=noreply@example.com
log4j.appender.MAIL.To=developer@example.com
log4j.appender.MAIL.Subject=Exception
log4j.appender.MAIL.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.MAIL.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %5r %-5p [%t] %c{2} - %m%n
```

.. the probability for several exceptions of the same type to occur, and possibly continuing until an issue is resolved is very high.

Is there a way of buffering output so that mails are only sent within given time intervals?

A nice solution would be to group exceptions on type and class it occurred in, but simply appending to a local log and sending a rolled log over timed intervals would suffice. The idea is to not receive hundreds or thousands of error reports from a stressed system, but rather receive vital information in time, and then not be bothered about the subsequent actions.

Is there a solution without implementing a `TriggeringEventEvaluator`?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just log the errors to a file, and have a custom script polling the file, sending mails on any intervals/messages you want? That way you have complete control. You could just log to a file and have a cron job mail the log from time to time. I think logging directly to mail is rarely a good idea.

Comment: Generally your proposal is a nice idea, but it's not very flexible. If I write a service I'd like the base functionality and configuration to be bundled within the application, so that it's easy to move it to another container.

Comment: I think it is very flexible but you are right in that it wouldn't be bundled with the application. We have used such a solution for a long time, but granted, we are not coding a product to be distributed,  just to our own platform.

Comment: What I meant by flexible is that I'd like to be able to reconfigure the appender settings (for different services) rather than recode scripts. There is of course nothing inflexible about your approach if the scripts have configuration. Then the only problem is that they aren't bundled with the applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this one: https://github.com/reaktor/log4j-email-throttle

Simple, but works fine for buffering.

Comment: It's not really an answer to the question, but I guess it is really the question that is wrong in this case. I'll give your solution a go, and even mark the question as answered. Thanks!